# How to perform stepwise regression without intercept?

Tags: regression, stepwise-regression

I have to implement a regression model and I have about 30 variables in the model. Some of the variables do not have much influence on the model, but I need to use a formalized method for eliminating variables. I ended up with the AIC and BIC methods and I have been using the `step` function in R. The problem is that I need to do a regression model that goes through the origin. In R I use the following statement for regression through the origin,

`g <- lm(Pcubes ~ 0 + ., data)`

and a regression with intercept

`g <- lm(Pcubes ~ ., data)`

I then use the `step` function as

`l <- step(g)`

and the summary for the new the regression model `l`, `summary(l)`. Whenever I use the regression through the origin, I get a summary from `summary(l)` where some variables are not significant to the model and I also get a new regression model that looks as follows,

```
lm(formula = Pcubes ~ X1 + X4 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X13 + X14 + X17 + 
    X18 + X23 + X24 + X25 + X29 + X30 + X40 + X41 + X44 + X45 + 
    X46 + X48 + X52 + X53 + X54 + X55 + X71 + X82 + X91 + X96 - 1, data = data)
```

The new model subtracts a 1. And the `step` function also results in different variables for regression through the origin and regression with intercept. S**o my questions are,** can I use the `step` function in R for regression through the origin or can I just ignore the `-1` in the model or should I use the regression with intercept to choose the best variables and implement the regression through the origin with those variables?

Comment: The R function `step` does [stepwise regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression), not a [step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function). (Search on `stepwise` here or for the `[stepwise-regression]` tag for lots of discussion of the problems with this.)

Comment: Are you aware that a "-1" is the same as "+0" in R formulas?

Answer (score 2):

For the lm model with intercept `lm(y~.)`, the simplest model to consider by `step` function is `lm(y~1)`. So it will try to drop the intercept at all.

For the lm model without intercept `lm(y~-1+.)`,  `step` function will compare the model family all without intercept but different predictor x.